# How to get the action from a button?

Tags: xcode

In my program, there are 5 five button. Different actions will be performed based on the choice of the button. However, I just assign one IBAction to all button. Is there any method that can help me to detect which button the users choose inside a single IBAction? Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't know xcode but are there any id fields possible for a button?

Comment: You ID items in your interface by declaring them in your header file...

IBOutlet UIButton *myButton1;

Then you can link these declarations to your interface so Xcode knows which interface items your talking about in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your buttons have their

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *menuButton;
```

You can change the function like this:

```
- (IBAction)actionButtons:(UIButton*)sender {
    if ([sender isEqual:menuButton]) {
        NSLog(@"Menu Pressed");
    }
}
```

This way you can use the tags for something else (I use them to denote in what stage I am of the interface for example)

PD: You might want your button to be weak, i got them linked as strong for a reason.

Answer (score 3):

Assign each of the buttons a unique `tag` property. Then, check this in your `IBAction` method:

```
- (IBAction)theActionDone:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    switch (button.tag)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            //do stuff for button one
            break;
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `sender` will be the calling objects.

```
- (IBAction)theActionDone:(id)sender;
```

If you have many buttons calling `theActionDone:` above, the `sender` is the button calling (either the cell or button control, either way you can work your way up from there).